# get active OS windows directly from java?

Tags: java

anyone knows how to get the active windows (OS native, not inside java app) using java ? I saw that RFT has a way of doing it

eg. IWindow activeWin = RationalTestScript.getScreen().getActiveWindow();

so I wondering what is the deal behind it ? is there any other method of doing it easier ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way in the JDK - I imagine RationalTestScript is using native code behind the scenes.

Consdier this: if there were a method in the JDK to get the native active window - what would it return? A `java.awt.Window` would not work, since that is a window specifically under java control.

You may have some success with [JNA](http://jna.dev.java.net), which provides native access to the window handle, but you just get a pointer/integer. You will then have to call OS functions to do anything useful with that. I expect RTS is doing this behind the IWindow interface.

Comment: thanks, it is fairly right what you are saying about return, let me have a look on JNA, eventually I will decompile the RFT class to see what they are doing. thanks